# Using Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, how can I update a column for every customer in the database?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create a function that updates every customer in a database called customers (the lastEmailed column), and I have tried multiple times using different query inputs, and execution methods (update, batchupdate, etc) and I am having no luck. This is what my chopped/commented code looks like, after messing around. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks! Also, the input style is in the format 2014-12-09 14:20:47 (datetime). ** this is a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

** this refers in particular to the updateTime function, I just included the rest of my DAO to help
** I want to update EVERY customer with the same value for lastEmailed only, every time the function is called.

```
@Repository            // creates the bean
public class CustomerDAO {

@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private RowMapper<Customer> rowMapper = new RowMapper<Customer>() {
    @Override
    public Customer mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int index) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerNumber(resultSet.getString("id"));
        customer.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("fName"));
        customer.setLastName(resultSet.getString("lName"));
        customer.setEmail(resultSet.getString("email"));
        customer.setStreet(resultSet.getString("street"));
        customer.setCity(resultSet.getString("city"));
        customer.setState(resultSet.getString("state"));
        customer.setZip(resultSet.getString("zip"));

        //Map Customer Fields Here

        return customer;
    }
};
public List<Customer> getCustomerList(){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS";
    List<Customer> customerList =this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
    return customerList;
}

 // ** in another class?
 //    public String toString(){
//        List<Customer> temp = this.getCustomerList();
 //
 //    }

public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS " +
            "(id, lname, fname, email, street,city, state,zip) VALUES (:id, :lname, :fname, :email, " +
            ":street, :city, :state, :zip)";

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("id", customer.getCustomerNumber());
    parameters.put("lname", customer.getLastName());
    parameters.put("fname", customer.getFirstName());
    parameters.put("email", customer.getEmail());
    parameters.put("street", customer.getStreet());
    parameters.put("city", customer.getCity());
    parameters.put("state", customer.getState());
    parameters.put("zip", customer.getZip());
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);

}

public void updateTime(String timeSent){
    String query = "UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed ='" + timeSent+"'";
//        String query = "UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed = ?";
//         String query = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS "
//        this.jdbcTemplate.
//        this.jdbcTemplate.executeppr
//        this.jdbcTemplate.update

//         jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed=?",timeSent);
//        SqlParameterSource [] parameterSource =     SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(this.getCustomerList().toArray());
//        this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (id,lastEmailed) VALUES     (:customerNumber, " +timeSent + ")", parameterSource);

}
}
```

Comment: When you say "for every customer in the database", do you want to set them all to have the same value in one shot, or do you mean have the capability to update any of them individually or as a group to have some specified value?

Comment: you question needs bit more details as it is not clear if you want to update all the customer records or some customer records or one customer record in one go. please provide details so we can help.

Comment: @Setu, sorry if I was unclear, I want to only update the lastEmail field, but for every customer in the database, in one shot.

Comment: @Todd, I would like every customer to all have the same value in the lastEmailed slot every time the function is called. Not a specific customer, or group, every customer

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe how I overlooked this, I pretty much had it in one of my previous functions, but didn't realize I only had to put one value in the map. Thanks for everyone who took the time to look at my code!

```
public void updateTime(String timeSent){
      String query = "UPDATE customers SET lastEmailed ='" + timeSent+"'";
     Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("lastEmailed", timeSent);
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(query,parameters);
 }
```