# java backend working fine sql prepare statement with no error but not updating oracle developer database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Trying to update a row in a table without primary key. I initially thought it was a problem with double quotation on the query and primary key issue. but i targeted all the columns to be on the query statement after 'Where' clause. But still the code not updating database properly. Where did I got wrong?

```
       @Override
        public void updateRows(CrudObject crudObject, String schema, String tableName) {
         System.out.println("Received crudObject: " + crudObject);
         try {
       // Prepare the SQL query
            for (CrudRows row : crudObject.getCrudRows()) {
         // For each row, construct the SQL query
       StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

        sqlBuilder.append("UPDATE ").append(schema).append(".").append(tableName).append(" SET ");

        List<String> setParts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CrudNewRowData columnData : row.getCrudNewRowData()) {
            setParts.add(columnData.getColumnName() + " = :" + "new_" + columnData.getColumnName());

            String columnNewDataValue = columnData.getColumnNewData();
            columnNewDataValue = "'" + columnNewDataValue + "'";
            params.addValue("new_" + columnData.getColumnName(), columnNewDataValue);
        }

        sqlBuilder.append(String.join(", ", setParts));

        // Construct WHERE clause
        List<String> whereParts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CrudOldRowData columnData : row.getCrudOldRowData()) {
            whereParts.add(columnData.getColumnName() + " = :" + "old_" +columnData.getColumnName());

            String columnOldDataValue = columnData.getColumnOldData();
            columnOldDataValue = "'" + columnOldDataValue + "'";
            params.addValue("old_" + columnData.getColumnName(), columnOldDataValue);
        }

        sqlBuilder.append(" WHERE ").append(String.join(" AND ", whereParts));

        // Execute the SQL update operation
        String sqlQuery = sqlBuilder.toString();
        String parameterValues = params.getValues().toString();

        System.out.println("Complete SQL: " + sqlQuery + " | Parameters: " + parameterValues);

        int rowsUpdated = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sqlBuilder.toString(), params);
        System.out.println("Rows updated: " + rowsUpdated);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}

}
```

the object passed in is like below:

```
{schemaName: 'ABCD', tableName: 'STUDENT', apiKey: 'student', crudMethod: 'PUT',         
crudRows: Array(1)}
apiKey: "student"
crudMethod: "PUT"
crudRows: Array(1)
0: crudNewRowData: Array(3)
0: {columnName: 'PART_NUMBER', columnNewData: '123456'}
1: {columnName: 'CONTROL_NUMBER', columnNewData: '78910'}
2: {columnName: 'ACC_NUMBER', columnNewData: '4'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
crudOldRowData: Array(3)
0: {columnName: 'PART_NUMBER', columnOldData: '123456'}
1: {columnName: 'CONTROL_NUMBER', columnOldData: '78910'}
2: {columnName: 'ACC_NUMBER', columnOldData: '3'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
schemaName: "ABCD"
tableName: "STUDENT"
```

on ORACLE developer SQL, the script below works fine:

```
UPDATE ABCD.STUDENT
SET  PART_NUMBER = '123456', CONTROL_NUMBER = '78910', ACC_NUMBER='4'
WHERE PART_NUMBER = '123456' AND CONTROL_NUMBER = '78910' AND  ACC_NUMBER='3' ;
```

but in JAVA IDE console produced no ERROR but database not updating:

```
Received crudObject: CrudObject(schemaName=ABCD, tableName=STUDENT, apiKey=Student, crudMethod=PUT, crudRows=[CrudRows(crudNewRowData=[CrudNewRowData(columnName=PART_NUMBER, columnNewData=123456), CrudNewRowData(columnName=CONTROL_NUMBER, columnNewData=78910), CrudNewRowData(columnName=ACC_NUMBER, columnNewData=4)], crudOldRowData=[CrudOldRowData(columnName=PART_NUMBER, columnOldData=123456), CrudOldRowData(columnName=CONTROL_NUMBER, columnOldData=78910), CrudOldRowData(columnName=ACC_NUMBER, columnOldData=3)])])

Complete SQL: UPDATE ABCD.STUDENT SET PART_NUMBER = :new_PART_NUMBER,     CONTROL_NUMBER = :new_CONTROL_NUMBER, ACC_NUMBER = :new_ACC_NUMBER WHERE PART_NUMBER = :old_PART_NUMBER AND CONTROL_NUMBER = :old_CONTROL_NUMBER   AND ACC_NUMBER = :old_ACC_NUMBER | Parameters: {new_PART_NUMBER='123456',   new_CONTROL_NUMBER='78910', new_ACC_NUMBER='4', old_PART_NUMBER='123456',   old_CONTROL_NUMBER='78910', old_ACC_NUMBER='3'}
Rows updated: 0
```

Comment: `new_ACDELCO_NUMBER='4'` the parameter name does not match the parameter placeholder in the SQL statement.

Comment: sorry , was a typo. i corrected it. console shows no error but 0 rows updated in database.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause matches no rows. That's what you should be debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by my colleague when he turned on the debug mode on showing the mapping of the params and it was showing have a single quotation marks around params. and after removing these two line below the update works:

```
columnNewDataValue = "'" + columnNewDataValue + "'";

columnOldDataValue = "'" + columnOldDataValue + "'";
```

Problem solved. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think there is a problem in adding data to MapSqlParameterSource
Key of the parameters must be the same as set parameter columns .
You should remove 'new' and 'old' from the parameters key.
The right code is like this

```
   `@Override
    public void updateRows(CrudObject crudObject, String schema, String tableName) {
     System.out.println("Received crudObject: " + crudObject);
     
   // Prepare the SQL query
        for (CrudRows row : crudObject.getCrudRows()) {
     // For each row, construct the SQL query
   StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    sqlBuilder.append("UPDATE ").append(schema).append(".").append(tableName).append(" SET      ");

    List<String> setParts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CrudNewRowData columnData : row.getCrudNewRowData()) {
        setParts.add(columnData.getColumnName() + " = :" + "new_" +      columnData.getColumnName());

        String columnNewDataValue = columnData.getColumnNewData();
        columnNewDataValue = "'" + columnNewDataValue + "'";
        params.addValue( columnData.getColumnName(), columnNewDataValue);
    }

    sqlBuilder.append(String.join(", ", setParts));

    // Construct WHERE clause
    List<String> whereParts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CrudOldRowData columnData : row.getCrudOldRowData()) {
        whereParts.add(columnData.getColumnName() + " = :" + "old_" +         columnData.getColumnName());

        String columnOldDataValue = columnData.getColumnOldData();
        columnOldDataValue = "'" + columnOldDataValue + "'";
        params.addValue(columnData.getColumnName(), columnOldDataValue);
    }

    sqlBuilder.append(" WHERE ").append(String.join(" AND ", whereParts));

    // Execute the SQL update operation
    String sqlQuery = sqlBuilder.toString();
    String parameterValues = params.getValues().toString();

    System.out.println("Complete SQL: " + sqlQuery + " | Parameters: " + parameterValues);

    int rowsUpdated = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sqlBuilder.toString(), params);
    System.out.println("Rows updated: " + rowsUpdated);
}`
```

Comment: i tried , not working, because the params have to be matching the place holder for set statements. on set statements has :new_columnName and :old_columnName, the params have to replace their placeholder values.

Comment: If it was a typo, the implication is you re-typed the code into StackOverflow.  How do we know there aren't more typos?  Always copy/paste directly from your IDE, NEVER retype code into your question.  I suggest you [edit] your post and ensure all the code and output matches reality.

Comment: sorry, i copied it from IDE but there is some sensitive data that i need to change and did not change the one you mentioned. Apologize.

Comment: Hi Sam You should create the SQL query same as that query that works in the SQL developer. there is some rules in using jdbcTemplate with parameters you can find it in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804022/using-spring-namedparameterjdbctemplate-how-can-i-update-a-column-for-every-cus

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).